# How can I make an animated avatar for gravatar.com?

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I was inspired by [this animated avatar](http://www.free-avatars.com/r-animated-92-dancing-kid-4750.html) from free-avatars.com:

[image: Please, no...]

Is it possible to use an animated GIF as an avatar on gravatar.com?  I couldn't get it to work, but maybe someone else knows a hack.

Comment: You should change your question to "How can I make an animated avatar to be used in gravatar?" or "Does gravatar service support animated images?".

Comment: And really, who *wouldn't* be inspired by that link?!?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't look forward to seeing animated avatars...

Comment: As an aside, I actually would like to get rid of all avatars from any third-party site, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/non-gravatar-avatar/5658#5658 But well, world peace is more important.

Comment: If this day would have to come, I would praise again Opera for giving me the choice to not animate images, per page.

Comment: But *can* you use Opera on Super User...? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/posting-questions-does-not-work-any-more-in-opera-9-64/13033#13033

Comment: @Arjan: Sure, I think I had only one minor display bug, with a beta version of the 10, never had any problem besides. I don't really consider Opera as buggy, especially since 10.0 release. Maybe simply Opera user are more likely to complain :]

Comment: Wow, my first controversial post.  I'm surprised "super users" are so threatened by tiny animations.  However, I'm very pleased to see some users thinking about how to make animation an optional feature in your browser.

Comment: OP, if you succeed, I would like to stab you in the eye with a cue-tip. One with vinegar on. Animated avatars are awful things and should be destroyed.

Comment: If Gravatar would ever support this, then I hope the website that displays the avatars can somehow opt to disable it...

Comment: Bounty? It is not possible, from what is stated in both answers, from an official source. A bounty won't bring you a magical answer to that..

Comment: As the official source, Gravatar, has confirmed this is not possible and not allowed, I have removed the bounty on this question and urge the OP to accept the highest voted answer. The bounty is not going to add any value, apart from creating another question with an answer that will never be accepted.

Answer (score 28):

AFAIK, this isn't possible.

Every time I upload an image, gravatar's system forces me to "crop" it. I believe they just extract the first frame from an animated image.

Check this [blog post](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/03/14/big-changes-afoot/), you can see in the comments where people are complaining about this issue and png transparency too.

EDIT: Since there's a bounty for this question, here is an another [quote from their official blog](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/09/02/better-image-detection/#comment-5615) answering to a user asking the same thing (emphasis is mine):

> Thunderm00n Says: September 3, 2008 at
>   2:31 pm
>
> Hey there! Nice work, but **why don`t
>   you accept moving gifs** or why we have
>   to resize our avartas (just use a type
>   of width and height attribute,
>   min-height/width should be 80px
>   max-height/width should be 120px) but
>   its a great work. Keep on!

...which is answered:

> apokalyptik Says: September 3, 2008 at
>   6:35 pm
>
> (...) @Thunderm00n — **It was a
>   conscious choice not to accept
>   animated images.** On the whole most
>   people don’t like them, and it can
>   seriously detract from the look and
>   feel of a site. Since we (all) are
>   guests on peoples web pages we do our
>   best to play nice with the other kids
>   while we are there.

Comment: `s/AFAIK/I really hope/g` and `s/isn't/will never be/g` ;-)

Comment: /concur
Dear Gravatar, Please do not consider adding support for animated avatars.
Yours sincerely
All right-thinking people of the interweb

Comment: This is definitely a case of 'feature' versus 'perceived bug'.

Comment: this makes me wonder, is there an alternative to gravatar? something that would accept gifs?

Answer (score 17):

This is really impossible. Yesterday I asked their support, and they said:

> Hello,
>
> We do not allow animated gravatar images.
>
> Cheers!
>       Demitrious Kelly

Comment: Good news, though "allowing" is not the same as "possible"...